# Is ERC 865 safe to use?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

Would like to implement ERC 865 (pay transfer fees with token instead of eth) or similar functionality in my smart contract. Is ERC 865 safe and audited currently? If not, is there any implementation out there that is safe to use?

Have been searching few similar implementation online and it seems that all of them has security issue. Glad to know if anyone actually use it on mainnet.

Comment: Honestly, even if one implementation was "safe" to use, highly likely that there are some security issues. In my opinion it would be best not to take the rest. Not aware of any "safe" contracts, I would trust a known flawed contracts rather than a unknown contract with no flaws because bugs are everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe is a very relative term here that has different meaning to different people. ERC 865 has got a lot of attention recently, and is (likely) on the *safer* side of  the wall.

With that said, it is not accepted as a standard and may have some issues or vulnerabilities.

bokkypoobah created an [implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865#issuecomment-362642721) on February 2nd, 2018. It has been in the wild for almost 8 months now. On May 1st, 2018, he [fixed a bug](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865#issuecomment-385741378) that was found after people began using it in production. You will see that people have continued to use and improve upon this implementation, but it has not yet been solidified.

Comment: Please note that ERC865 reference code currently (Jan 25 2019) has a vulnerability where the signed signature can be replayed